# Entendiendo sum() en Python

Tags: python, sum

En la documentación de [Python](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functions.html#sum) me encuentro que la definición de sum puede o no admitir varios parámetros como indica `sum(iterable[, start])` extraído de esa misma documentación.

La ejecución de este código está bastante clara y es el uso normal de sum

```
numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sum(numbers))
#Resultado 15


numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
print(sum(numbers, 10))
#Resultado 25
```

Lo que no entiendo es el funcionamiento de este código

```
def solution(number):
   return sum(x for x in range(number) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

Con ese código suma todos los números entre 0 y number que sean divisibles por 3 o por 5.

No entiendo su funcionamiento. Creo que hay dos parámetros pero no están separados por una coma, ya que si la pongo da un error de sintaxis. Es decir,

```
 def solution(number):
   return sum(x, for x in range(number) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0)
```

no funciona.

Agradecería una explicación de este código.

Comment: Investiga list comprehensions, son muy similares y vas a entender el por qué no deberías añadir una coma en ese código. Ejemplo: https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/basics/list-comprehensions-in-python

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En realidad, la llamada es con un único parámetro que es el *generador*. De modo explícito sería así:

```py
def solution(number):
   return sum( (x for x in range(number) if x % 3 == 0 or x % 5 == 0) )
```

Si hubieras usado el segundo parámetro habría que haber dejado los paréntesis internos. Pero se considera redundantes si sólo está el generador como único argumento. Pasa en general con otras funciones que aceptan iterables.

Comment: Pero si no lleva yield, ¿también es un generador? Me pierdo con eso.

Comment: Existe un modo compacto para crear generadores mediante las [expresiones generadoras](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#generator-expressions), con sintaxis similar a las [compresiones de listas](https://docs.python.org/3.7/reference/expressions.html#displays-for-lists-sets-and-dictionaries) (denominadas _"displays"_).